# Setting Timeout for network failure when executing a query on table storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

I am writing a retry system that will retry retreiving data from windows azure table storage if the network fails.

My problem is that when the network fails, reading the data (the second line of code below) waits till a certain timeout then throws an exception.

```
               Result = Table.ExecuteQuery(query);
               Console.WriteLine(Result.ElementAt(0).Timestamp);
```

How can i manipulate this timeout value?

Answer (score 2):

You set the `Timeout` property of the `DataServiceContext`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext.timeout.aspx